# how to add explicit wait in drop down in selenium which is dependent on another dropdown?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

[image: MY DROPDOWN]how to add explicit wait in drop down using selenium until it finds the text ?

[image: MY CODE]

Comment: i want to add explicit wait till it finds "fa"

Comment: Why you need to wait for `option`- it's already in page source? Do you get any exception with your code? Do you have a problem with finding `select` element?

Comment: i have 2 dropdown.. 2nd dropdown is dependent on 1st dropdown.. so need tto add some wait time

Comment: So Wiki page is just for example? Can you share exact `HTML` for both drop-down elements or target page `URL`?

Comment: I have added the picture. u can see the following dropdown is disabled till the first one is enabled

Comment: please check the updated question

Answer (score 2):

Try this below code.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);          //add Explicit Wait
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your xpath"))));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your xpath")).click();   //After Explicit Wait Click on WebElement
```

Comment: If this answer is `helpful` to you, then please mark this answer as `Accepted`.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriver wait = new WebDriver(Driver, Seconds);
boolean status;
```

status = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(""))) != null;

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean waitForElement( String element, int timeout) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(appiumDriver, timeout/1000);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(element)));
        return true;
    }

element is the xpath.

and when you run this function it will wait for timeout(millisecond ) max for the element to appear .
if the element comes early than it will break and return true which means element is present.
```

Comment: PLEASE CHECK THE UPDATED QUESTION